# what is different between a.Equals(b) and Equals(object a,object b) in c#

Tags: c#-4.0, version

Please explain me what is different between this two statement.

first statement throw the exception and second one returns the Boolean value

```
Version a = null;

if(a.Equals(null)) // throw the exception

if(Equals(a,null)) // return the bool value true
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot call `a.Equals` without initializing `a` with an object, otherwise it will throw `NullReferenceExcption`, But `Equals` is a static method, it checks whether the two references passed to it are same or not, these references can have null values.

Comment: Means if object a is null even if initialization we can't use a.Equals() correct.

Comment: Yeah.. I forgot to mention it.

Answer (score 2):

`a.Equals` is an instance method - if `a` is `null` it will throw a `NullReferenceExcption` since you are calling a method on `a` which is `null`.

The other `Equals` is a static method on `Object` - it will not throw. If both objects being passed in are `null` it returns `true`.